# How to obtain private RSA key(private) as byte array in pgp file?

Tags: rsa, gnupg, private-key

I know that

```
gpg --export-secret-keys KEY_NAME > KEY_FILE
```

prints the key to file in pgp format. But what I need is to obtain the 2048 byte RSA key as byte array.

Why I need that? I am trying to convert a signing struture that uses RSA key from file that contains the keys as byte arrays. Something like.

```
bac6388....
```

I want to use my pgp key in this format first. Then I will start to use pgp keys.

When I run

```
 gpg --export-secret-keys KEY_NAME | xxd -p
```

it prints out what I want as below.

```
 9503be04556716da010800c92a2dee0cd36694c3337b9845d9d3653d9f02
 8398ebbfdc054657df710ab9d44cdd8bcfe9ea182dd257a629bd3d7ca045
 9878b7384b265f5967117ea314b1b1a3a6e376115de26cd90d59327920b5
 4af9022e1d60ec82.............
```

What I need is just the 2048 bit (256 byte) RSA key in this array.
Also openssh(pem,crt) or openssl formats or even C/C++ is welcomed since I can translate the key to these formats.

I just want to get private key as byte array.

Thanks

Comment: I wrote 2048 byte at start. I wanted to say 2048 bit (256 byte)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi here is the solution(on Ubnuntu)

First be sure that you removed the password of your key

```
 gpg --edit-key KEY_NAME
```

Write
     passwd
on gpg consoler and press ENTER two times for new password.

Then
     gpg --export-secret-keys KEY_NAME > KEY_FILE

You need to install pgpdump

```
 sudo apt-get install pgpdump
```

Run

```
pgpdump -i -p KEY_FILE
```

Dumps all components of RSA key.

Answer (score 0):

this posts I believe can help you through java to obtain your RSA private key

[How to Load RSA Private Key From File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243018/how-to-load-rsa-private-key-from-file)

[PGP Encryption and Decryption with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9596298/pgp-encryption-and-decryption-with-java)

[Extract public/private key from PKCS12 file for later use in SSH-PK-Authentification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9497719/extract-public-private-key-from-pkcs12-file-for-later-use-in-ssh-pk-authentifica)

check it