# PGP encryption and decryption in java

Tags: java, public-key-encryption, pgp, openpgp

I have the **public key** which is shared by client for PGP file encrpytion.
I am using Java 1.7 and this question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9596298/7030357).

Unfortunately none of those solutions are working for me or **outdated**.

Can someone please share the working implementation or guide if they have any?
Code with comments is preferred.

**What i have done so far:**

Tried implementating using BouncyCastle and OpenPGP API. 
Didn't succeed.

Comment: Can you show us your implementation using BouncyCastle? We can probably tell you what you did wrong. Keep in mind that StackOverflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta implementations are from Internet and all i am getting are compilation errors since they are written in 2011 or so and outdated. That is why i am asking for working guides which are already published. I know SO is not a code writing service and i am not asking for it.

Comment: With statement `Didn't succeed` could you be more specific? (what compilation errors, code sample, ..)  We may be able to help you find out what went wrong / what to fix. There are many answered questions here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pgp+java) so we see no reason copy/paste it for you