# Generate Files from Oracle with signature

Tags: oracle, plsql, gnupg, pgp

I would like to sign a file with gpg when creating the file using plsql from an Oracle application. I've already googled a lot and found nothing that works for me. The signature must be read from another application. Therefor I have to use gpg for key generation and signation. 
Does anyone have any idea? Thanks Andreas

Answer (score 1):

There's a few different ways I can think of that you could do this:

1. [Purchase the commercial OraPGP library](https://www.didisoft.com/ora-pgp/tutorial/signing/), which does exactly what you want.
2. [Do it in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9596298/pgp-encryption-and-decryption-with-java) (using Bouncy Castle libraries or similar), and load that into your database using `loadjava`.
3. Install GPG on your server, and [execute it as an external OS command](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9533837800346646784).

Finally, you could write your own OpenPGP implementation in PL/SQL.

Comment: Thanks for the quick help. The Orapgp encrypts the text, although the 'sign'
function only seems to sign. But I only need a signed text. Is that also
possible?

Comment: I'm sorry, I haven't actually used their software. But from their example, it looks like you can sign text. I think they have a trial version you could test with.

Comment: Yes I have tried it, when I sign something with the function 'sign' I get an
encrypted text as a result. Not exactly what I want. Maybe me customer will accept it.